# Symfony2: get the id of the persisted object

Tags: database, symfony, persistence, entity

I have two entity: User and Person.

In the entity User I need the id of the associated person: user_id.

When I am creating a new user, I have to create first the person and then the user.
In the user, I have to put the id of the corresponding person and for that I need to get the id of the persisted object person which is an auto increment.

Is it possible to get the id of the object after:

```
$em->persist($person);
$em->flush();
```

And how can I do this?

The alternative is to search the biggest id it the table Person and take this one but I think there should be a better and easier method to get the id of the persisted object.

In php for example, when I execute

```
$articleID = $_DB->queryRaw((....);
```

I am getting the id like that.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

[Symfony2 with Doctrine](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#persisting-objects-to-the-database) as default ORM will automatically generate an ID after data stored in database. So you can call the ID by `->getId()`

```
$id = $person->getId();
```

Comment: Thank you @HHabibillah, this works. The only thing: there is no var in php, only $id = $person->getId();
If you can edit this please and I will accept your answer.

Comment: Thank for your correction. I have edit to be a correct syntax.

Comment: Thank you, I will accept the answer in 1h, I have my launch break now.

Comment: Hello @Habibillah,
Can I get the id with getId() if I have only used $em->persist($person); ?
I have not yet used flush method but I want the id of $person entity object (for this example :) )

Comment: @AshishShah yes, but please try your self

Comment: Sure. I will check. Thank You,